# Использование инициализированного метода File в других функциях

Tags: java, файлы, filewriter

В main инициализировал функцию (может и не функция, класс, не знаю как это правильно назвать)

```
File UserOut = new File("C:\\lol\\Output.txt");
    UserOut.createNewFile();
```

Хочу использовать метод FileWriter для записи в этот файл, но в другой функции

```
private static void Compressing (int R, int start, char[] BMPSort, int NumberOfRepeats) throws Exception
{
    FileWriter WriteUserOut = new FileWriter(тут должно быть UserOut, но функция его, естественно, не видит);
```

Как сделать UserOut в той функции видимым ? Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: передать в функцию параметром

Comment: @Sublihim, спасибо, все работает. Просто не знал, как указать параметром File.

Comment: Небольшое дополнение касаемо приведенного Вами кода, ознакомьтесь с [Java Code Conventions ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) очень поможет в будущем.