# Использование FileWriter в цикле

Tags: java, filewriter

В main создал файл Output. В него записываю данные через отдельную функцию. Но эта функция вызывается у меня в цикле несколько раз. И записывает в файл только самый последний результат, а мне нужно записывать в строчку без пробелов результат каждого цикла.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

File UserOut = new File("C:\\lol\\Output.txt");
UserOut.createNewFile();

while(G != UncompressedText.length()-1) {
Compressing(NumberOfRepeats, UserOut);
}

 private static void Compressing (int NumberOfRepeats, File UserOut) throws Exception
    {
        FileWriter WriteUserOut = new FileWriter(UserOut);
        for( byte i = 0; i < R; i++)
        {
            if ( start == 0)
            {
                if(NumberOfRepeats != 1) {
                    WriteUserOut.write(NumberOfRepeats + "" + BMPSort[BMPSort.length - 1] + "|");
                } else {
                    WriteUserOut.write(BMPSort[BMPSort.length - 1] + "|");
                }
            }
        WriteUserOut.close();
    }
```

Спасибо за советы.

Comment: В приведённом вами коде нет ни цикла, ни записи. Покажите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Использование инициализированного метода File в других функциях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784100/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-file-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Добавил пример. Спасибо за замечание.